# Flutter installation problem, cant able accept license with letter Y or y

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

When ever I try to accept the licenses I am getting the error as shown in the figure .I had tried with Capital 'Y' and small 'y', but no working. (Please note that I didn't pressed enter key after the message is displayed).  I am attaching flutter doctor --android licenses and flutter -v

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just don't press any other button other than 'y' when it asks `Review licenses that have not been accepted (y/N)?` :)

Comment: That line C:\Users\user>, is automatically generated , it is not allowing to type 'y' near to near " Review licenses that have not been accepted (y/N)? " . When ever I run flutter doctor --android-licenses, the result is like as shown in figure (with out pressing any key on key board).. It is not allowing me to type on the same line. I tried to delete "C:\Users\user>" but it is not deleting also

Comment: Maybe it has accepted. Can you run flutter doctor -v and see if licenses were accepted?

Comment: I had attached the image of my flutter -v in the question, please have a look

Comment: maybe try the same thing differently? Have a look at this: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14942#issuecomment-387564336

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had this problem and it took days for me to solve this.. This is happening because of the antivirus installed in your system.. check your sdk\tools\bin folder, there should be file named sdkmanager.bat if that is absent means antivirus is deleting that file, same with archquery.bat , these two files are deleted by antivirus... go to msconfig in windows and to services , hide all Microsoft services then you will see anti virus running in your system.. uninstall that using control pannel.. then reinstall android studio ,, your system will work 100%

Comment: Yes you are right, sdkmanager.bat is not there.. Thanks you very much

Comment: Ohoo.. Thank you very much it is working .. you are a life saver

Answer (score 0):

You are terminating the previous session and trying to press 'y' or 'Y'. You need to answer that question on that line. It should be like this:

```
  Review licenses that have not been accepted (y/N)? y
```

Comment: That line C:\Users\user>, is automatically generated , it is not allowing to type 'y' near to near " Review licenses that have not been accepted (y/N)? " . When ever I run flutter doctor --android-licenses, the result is like as shown in figure (with out pressing any key on key board).. It is not allowing me to type on the same line. I tried to delete "C:\Users\user>" but it is not deleting also..